# Regex to validate numbers and forward slashes for date

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, regex

Hi I am trying to wright Regular Expression for date mm/dd/yyyy C#.
I have this

```
^(0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](19|20)\d\d$
```

But it doesn't work
[image]

How to do so it will works with 3/1/2013 and with 03/01/2013

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? How can we help if you don't even tell us the problem?

Comment: If i insert date like mm/dd/yyyy it shows that it is in correct

Comment: When using "or", remember to group units that should stick together with a non capturing group. Your second parenthesised expression is matching zero followed by a number from 1 to 9, or a numbers between 10 and 29 or 3, followed by either of 0 or 1.

Comment: then maybe you should put that in your question?

Comment: `3/1/2013` isn't mm/dd/yyyy format. You need to have the zeros there. Or change your regex to make the zeros optional.

Comment: how to do so it will works with `3/1/2013` and with `03/01/2013`?

Comment: Make the zeros optional, so `((?:0?[1-9])|(?:1[012]))[- /.]((?:0?[1-9])|(?:[12][0-9])|(?:3[01])).....`

Comment: Use DateTime.TryParseExact instead. It's got all the logic built in already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree that you should use `DateTime` methods for this. But if you want to make the leading zeros optional you can add a `?` after them, like so:

```
^(0?[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](19|20)\d\d$
```

Answer (score 7):

Don't use regular expressions, use `DateTime.TryParse` or `DateTime.TryParseExact`.

Also be aware of the current culture and the user's expectations. Americans use "MM/dd/yyyy" but the rest of the world (generally) uses "dd/MM/yyyy", both are indistinguishable for large ranges of dates.

Comment: app will used only in US and I am using Ajax datatime picker

Comment: Just in case you're using JSON input using MS serialized dates and failing to tryparse the values, try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1263732/how-to-pass-a-json-date-value-via-asp-net-mvc-using-json-net